# stop \animategraphics using mouse click

Tags: animations, animate

I used following command to create an animation inside my beamer presentation. 
Using below command, I can run animation whenever I want during my talk on slide.

```
   \animategraphics[loop, width=0.45\textwidth, height=0.35\textheight]{1}{pics/animation/step_}{0}{20}}
```

Since I have embedded two animation inside one Slide, I would like to stop first animation using mouse click (Just as way as I run it), then I click on the second animation to run.

I will appreciate if anyone can help me by giving me some hints.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

using controls and loop option together.

```
\animategraphics[controls,loop, trim=12.5cm 3.5cm 12.5cm 4.2cm, width=0.45\textwidth, height=0.35\textheight]{1}{pics/animation/prog_with_step/step_}{2}{20}}
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use controls to pause/run an animation:

Animations pause when the mouse button is pressed while the pointer is over the animation area. Keep the button pressed while moving it out and the animation remains paused.

After the next click the animation continues.

BTW, the players `[AV]Player.swf` of the `media9` package behave in the same way.